# How to call fragment method from java class?

Tags: java, android

I try to call fragment method from java class:
I know there many of questions on stack overflow on this topic, but my case is different

ConnectionAsyncTask.java :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.util.List;

public class ConnectionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    Activity activity;
    private EventListener listener;

    public ConnectionAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
        this.activity=activity;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String content =HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
        return content;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        List<Country> countries= CountryJasonParser.getObjectFromJason(s);
        if (countries != null) {
            String s1 = "";

                s1=s1+"\n"+"" + countries.get(0).getDes() ;
        //i want to call DisplyOnTextView(s1) 
        } 
    }
}
```

countryfragment.java:

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class countryfragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        TextView desc;

        public countryfragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            ConnectionAsyncTask connectionAsyncTask = new ConnectionAsyncTask(getActivity());
//This is a server which contains data to load it            connectionAsyncTask.execute("http://www.mocky.io/v2/570d3677270000f600dc29b6");
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countryfragment,container,false);
            desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

            return view;
        }
        public void DisplyOnTextView(String s) {
            desc.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

---

The result must be:
Display data on text view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public class ConnectionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    Activity activity;
    private EventListener listener;
    private TextView mTextView

    public ConnectionAsyncTask(Activity activity, TextView txt) {
        this.activity=activity;
       this.mTextView=txt;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String content =HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
        return content;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        List<Country> countries= CountryJasonParser.getObjectFromJason(s);
        if (countries != null) {
            String s1 = "";

                s1=s1+"\n"+"" + countries.get(0).getDes() ;

                mTextView.setText(s1);
        } 
    }
}
```

and then

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countryfragment,container,false);
        desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        ConnectionAsyncTask connectionAsyncTask = new ConnectionAsyncTask(getActivity(), desc);
        connectionAsyncTask.execute("http://www.mocky.io/v2/570d3677270000f600dc29b6");

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: This is not the ideal way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly update your UI view from the `AsyncTask`. For your purpose you can have a listener so that it triggers a function callback in your `countryfragment.java` and from the callback function you can have your `TextView` updated with the result.

You already have an interface first like this I guess.

```
public interface EventListener {
    public void responseReceiver(String result);
}
```

Now in your `Fragment` implement the `EventListener` and `Override` the `responseReceiver` method.

```
public class countryfragment extends 
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    , EventListener {

    // Other code goes here 

    // Override the callback function
    @Override
    public void responseReceiver(String result) {
        DisplyOnTextView(result);
    }
}
```

Now when starting the `AsyncTask` you need to pass the correct listener like this:

```
ConnectionAsyncTask connectionAsyncTask = new ConnectionAsyncTask(getActivity());
connectionAsyncTask.listener = this;
connectionAsyncTask.execute();
```

Now change your `onPostExecute` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    List<Country> countries= CountryJasonParser.getObjectFromJason(s);
    if (countries != null) {
        String s1 = "";

         s1=s1+"\n"+"" + countries.get(0).getDes() ;
         listener.responseReceiver(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, using listener and interface, override the method, but now i added this "connectionAsyncTask.listener = this;" but i get an error on listener

Comment: What is the error? And did you add the `EventListener` in the fragment declaration like this - `public class countryfragment extends 
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    , EventListener `

Answer (score 0):

you just need to send a listener from the activity to the asyncTask to call it from **onPostExecute**

code:

```
    public class Task extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    private TaskListener _listenr;
    public Task(TaskListener listener) {
        _listenr = listener;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       String res = "";

       //some logic

       return res;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //some logic
        if(_listenr!=null)
        {
            _listenr.onRetrieveData(s);
        }
    }

    public interface TaskListener
    {
        public void onRetrieveData(String res);
    }
}

Fragment:

    public class countryfragment extends Activity implements TaskListener {
    TextView desc;

    public countryfragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ConnectionAsyncTask connectionAsyncTask = new ConnectionAsyncTask(this);
//This is a server which contains data to load it            connectionAsyncTask.execute("http://www.mocky.io/v2/570d3677270000f600dc29b6");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countryfragment,container,false);
        desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

        return view;
    }
    public void DisplyOnTextView(String s) {
        desc.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetrieveData(String res)
    {
        //some logic here with res

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite using AsyncTask is not recommended for HTTP calls, you might want to create an interface in your ConnectionAsyncTask, like

```
interface ConnectionAsyncTaskCallback{

    void performAction(String s);
}
```

And next implement this interface in your fragment

```
    public class countryfragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, ConnectionAsyncTask.ConnectionAsyncTaskCallback
```

You will have to implement the `performAction(String s)` method, which will contain `desc.setText(s);`

Finally, in `ConnectionAsyncTask` add an member `ConnectionAsyncTaskCallback callback;` which you will pas in the constructor and call finally on the `onPostExecute` (`callback.performAction(s1);`).

**TL;DR, this is the modified code:**

ConnectionAsyncTask :

```
    public class ConnectionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    Activity activity;
    private EventListener listener;
    private ConnectionAsyncTaskCallback callback;

    public ConnectionAsyncTask(Activity activity, ConnectionAsyncTaskCallback callback) {
        this.activity=activity;
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String content =HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
        return content;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        List<Country> countries= CountryJasonParser.getObjectFromJason(s);
        if (countries != null) {
            String s1 = "";

                s1=s1+"\n"+"" + countries.get(0).getDes() ;
        //i want to call DisplyOnTextView(s1) 
            callback.performAction(s1);
        } 

    }

    interface ConnectionAsyncTaskCallback {

        void performAction(String s);
    }
}
```

countryfragment class:

```
public class countryfragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, ConnectionAsyncTask.ConnectionAsyncTaskCallback {
        TextView desc;

        public countryfragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            ConnectionAsyncTask connectionAsyncTask = new ConnectionAsyncTask(getActivity());
//This is a server which contains data to load it            connectionAsyncTask.execute("http://www.mocky.io/v2/570d3677270000f600dc29b6");
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countryfragment,container,false);
            desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void performAction(String s) {
            desc.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
}
```